# run-time cache reconfiguration

Tags: caching, simulation, cpu-architecture

I am working on a project where I have to find the best cache configuration for a specific benchmark by implementing a heuristic algorithm. I am done with the algorithm part but not getting the idea to implement the run-time reconfiguration ( block size , associativity, line size) technique. I am using simplescalar wattch tool.

Is it feasible to write a Perl script to implement the algorithm for each benchmark and to drive the simulator till we achieve the best cache configuration. If yes then is it possible to find an example.

please help me!

Comment: Yes, a perl script is an excelent idea. You could also use another scripting language like python or ruby. Running simplescalar from the perl script should be simple. You can pass the cache configuration with command line parameters. Just save the output from simplescalar into a file like "benchmark.sz4096.as4.ls64.out" for future reference, parse the file and extract energy and/or performance data. Feed that data into your algorithm and repeat with new parameters. Feel free to ask more specific questions about perl. The more detailed your question is, the more helpful the answers will be.

Comment: Thanks a lot Mackie for your reply. It helped me in a great way. Now I am going to drive wattch tool using a simple perl script with SPEC. If   I get any error while running , I may have some more specific questions.  It is very nice of you to answer my question in detail.